# LM Interaction omits different levels using * and :

Tags: r, regression, lm

I'm running linear model with interaction.

When I use the asterix `*` interaction term, the first level is omitted(in order to prevent multicollinearity).  
However, when I use the colon `:` interaction term the last level  is omitted. I want it to keep consistent and remove the same level.

When I manually move the first level to be the last level, I get the results I expect to have.

```r
library(data.table)
library(forcats)
library(stargazer)
dt<-data.table("id"=as.factor(rep(c("a","b","c","d"),2)),
               "y"=rnorm(20),
               "time"=as.factor(rep(1:5,each=4)))
dt$treat<-as.factor(ifelse(dt$id=="a"|dt$id=="b",1,0))


lm1<-lm(y~factor(id)+factor(time)*factor(treat),dt)
lm2.wrong<-lm(y~factor(id)+factor(time):factor(treat),dt)
### Here is my Fix
dt$time<-fct_relevel(dt$time,"1", after = Inf) # ":" Interaction removes the last level...
lm2.right<-lm(y~factor(id)+factor(time):factor(treat),dt)
stargazer(lm1,lm2.wrong,lm2.right,type = "text")
```

Here are the results:

```r
==========================================================
                                  Dependent variable:     
                             -----------------------------
                                           y              
                                (1)       (2)       (3)   
----------------------------------------------------------
factor(id)b                   -0.074    -0.074    -0.074  
                              (0.481)   (0.481)   (0.481) 

factor(id)c                   -0.619     1.044    -0.619  
                              (0.833)   (0.833)   (0.833) 

factor(id)d                   -0.019    1.644*    -0.019  
                              (0.833)   (0.833)   (0.833) 

factor(time)2                 -0.425                      
                              (0.760)                     

factor(time)3                  0.036                      
                              (0.760)                     

factor(time)4                  0.995                      
                              (0.760)                     

factor(time)5                 -0.061                      
                              (0.760)                     

factor(treat)1                                            


factor(time)1:factor(treat)0             0.061            
                                        (0.760)           

factor(time)2:factor(treat)0            -0.364    -0.425  
                                        (0.760)   (0.760) 

factor(time)3:factor(treat)0             0.098     0.036  
                                        (0.760)   (0.760) 

factor(time)4:factor(treat)0             1.056     0.995  
                                        (0.760)   (0.760) 

factor(time)5:factor(treat)0                      -0.061  
                                                  (0.760) 

factor(time)1:factor(treat)1            1.724*            
                                        (0.760)           

factor(time)2:factor(treat)1   0.090     1.389    -0.335  
                              (1.075)   (0.760)   (0.760) 

factor(time)3:factor(treat)1   0.180    1.941**    0.217  
                              (1.075)   (0.760)   (0.760) 

factor(time)4:factor(treat)1  -2.462*    0.257    -1.467* 
                              (1.075)   (0.760)   (0.760) 

factor(time)5:factor(treat)1  -1.663              -1.724* 
                              (1.075)             (0.760) 

Constant                       0.744    -0.980     0.744  
                              (0.589)   (0.589)   (0.589) 

----------------------------------------------------------
Observations                    20        20        20    
R2                             0.695     0.695     0.695  
Adjusted R2                    0.275     0.275     0.275  
Residual Std. Error (df = 8)   0.760     0.760     0.760  
F Statistic (df = 11; 8)       1.656     1.656     1.656  
==========================================================
Note:                          *p<0.1; **p<0.05; ***p<0.01
```

I expected the the first two specification to omit the first level (`factor(time)1`). Without modifying the levels manually. Any way of doing it systematically?

Comment: `A*B` is actually expanding to `A + B + A:B` (see `?formula`) so if you want the same model with both notations, make sure you also include the variables involved in the interaction as main effects in the formula.

Comment: I saw the ?formula, and  know the expanding. This is simply not what I meant,
I expect `factor(time)1:factor(treat)0` in the `lm2.wrong` to be omitted just like `factor(time)1` removed in lm1.
Take a look and see that in regression 1,3 all the coef of `factor(time)i` is the same as `factor(time)i:factor(treat)0`in regression 3.
This is what I expected to happen automatically.

Comment: This two models help me to identify two different aspect of the problem. 
lm1 allows me to see whether the treated group has different trend comparing to the control.
lm2(.right) let me see whether both the treated and control time trend are different then zero. 
When both regression have the same base it much easier to interpret their results.